# Palindrome incorrect results.

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a palindrome checker. And now it seems that my lengthChecker() is no longer being called, nor is the condition whenever a word isn't a palindrome, then say it's not a palindrome. What could be the issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Lesson #6 Homework</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/palindrome.js"></script>
   </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Is it a Palindrome?</h1>
  <div id="mainCont">
     <p>Hello. Please enter a word, and I'll see if it is a palindrome.</p>
     <p>Word:
        <input type="text" id="str" name="string" />
        <button id="checkInput">Submit</button>
     </p>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS as of now:

```
function lengthChecker() {
var str = document.getElementById("str").value;
if (str.length > 10 ) {
    alert("Sorry. Your input surpasses the 10 characters maximum. Please try again.")
    return false;
} else if (str.length == 0) {
alert ("Sorry. Your input is too short, and doesn't meet the 10 characters maximum. Please try again.")
    return false;
}
palindrome();
}

function palindrome() {
var revStr = "";
var str = document.getElementById("str").value;
var i = str.length;
for (var j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
   revStr = revStr + str.charAt(j);
}
if (str == revStr) {
   isPalindrome();
} else {
   alert(str + " -is not a Palindrome");
}
}

function isPalindrome() {
    alert(str + " is a Palindrome.");
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , function(e){
var el = document.getElementById("checkInput");
el.addEventListener("click", isPalindrome);
});
```

Comment: Seems to be working here? http://jsfiddle.net/ocjbzghf/

Comment: I get that error when I test this in Chrome. Also, what am I doing to cause it to say [object HTMLInputElement] is a Palindrome. I would like it to show the user's input.

Comment: HTML loads from top to bottom. Your JavaScript loads before any of your elements are created. In general, it is best practice to keep your script tags at the end of your body. This also helps with page loads.

Comment: Thanks but it seems that when I test the code like enter cat or dog which aren't palindromes it doesn't touch the is not a palindrome.

Comment: You aren't calling `lengthChecker` anywhere, so it's unclear why do you expect it to be called. And it seems you should be calling `palindrome` on button click, not `isPalindrome`.

Answer (score 0):

You have your Javascript linked in the `head` element, so it is executed **before**  the `<button id="checkInput">` gets into the DOM. Move it to the end of `body` or make it `defer`red.

Comment: Is it valid for the script tag to be and the end of the body tag? I thought usually it should be within the head tag?

Comment: yes it is valid and best practice to write your script at the end of body tag

Comment: It is and it is a considered quite a good practice. If you insist on script in the head, use the mentioned defer attribute or call any DOM related stuff from within function bound to window.onload or called from DOMContentLoaded listener (like the other answer suggests).